# How does the hermitian sesquilinear form look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, sesquilinear-forms

How does the hermitian sesquilinear form look like?

I mean some concrete example. I only found the abstract definitions but I would like to try diagonalize such forms or look at its signature, see the difference compared to the classic billinear forms.

Comment: Ok, this type of form is written at my linear algebra's demands for a written exam (calculations, not the theory) and I wasnt able to find any examples and I am not sure what would that calculation be about.

Comment: Take for example the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a two-dimensional hermitian space: $$L(u,v)=a_{11}\bar{u}_1 v_1 + a_{12}\bar{u}_1 v_2 + a_{21}\bar{u}_2 v_1 + a_{22}\bar{u}_2 v_2.$$ 
Here the matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ is hermitian: $$a_{ji} = \bar{a}_{ij}.$$ 
(Please observe that this property implies that the diagonal elements of $A$ are real numbers). In matrix notation: $L(u,v)=u^H A v$, where $u^H$ is the conjugate transpose of the column vector $u$. 
The quadratic form associated to $L$ is 
$$Q(u)=L(u,u)=u^H A u = a_{11}|u_1|^2 + a_{12}\bar{u}_1 u_2 + a_{21}\bar{u}_2 u_1 +a_{22}|u_2|^2 = a_{11}|u_1|^2 + 2 Re(a_{12}\bar{u}_1 u_2) + a_{22}|u_2|^2 .$$ 
In the last line we have exploited the relation $a_{21} = \bar{a}_{12}$: 
$$ a_{12} \bar{u}_1 u_2 + a_{21} \bar{u}_2 u_1 = a_{12} \bar{u}_1 u_2 + \bar{a}_{12} \cdot \overline{\bar{u}_1 u_2} = a_{12} \bar{u}_1 u_2 + \overline{a_{12} \bar{u}_1 u_2} = 2 Re(a_{12}\bar{u}_1 u_2).$$

Now it is up to you to generalize this object to $n$-dimensional hermitian spaces and also to apply the spectral theorem to the hermitian matrix $A$ in such a way to get to the canonical form of $Q(u)$.